# Creating PPT table runs intolerably SLOW

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am using Excel vba to create a table in a powerpoint slide and export data to said table. It's a basic calendar of events. The table builds so slow. It's 25 rows (header + 24 hours) and 9 (for a M-F) or 11 (including weekends) columns depending on whether the user clicks a 5-day button or a 7-day button.

I have separate subs for the 9 column version and the 11 column version. Both tables are building incredibly slow. It takes so long to adjust the row heights specifically. Once the row heights are set the table populates fast enough. The 9 column version code is below abbreviated not to include every row of time. Is there any way to speed things up?

```
Sub BuildFiveDayTable()

Dim BREtable as PowerPoint.Shape

Set BREtable = NewBREslide.Shapes.AddTable(25, 9, 1, 15, 719.25, 486)       'BREtable and NewBREslide are public variables decalred as Powerpoint shape and slide respectively.
BREtable.Name = "BREtable"

BREtable.Table.ApplyStyle ("5940675A-B579-460E-94D1-54222C63F5DA")     'No Fill, Table Style

BREtable.Table.Rows(1).Height = 14.4

For i = 2 to BREtable.Table.Rows.count         'steps through each row setting height. This is what runs slow.
     BREtable.Table.Rows(i).Height = 19.44
Next i

For i = 1 To BREtable.Table.Rows.count
     For j = 1 to BREtable.Table.Columns.count
          With BREtable.Table.Cell(i,j).Shape.TextFrame
               .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
               .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
               .TextRange.Font.Size = 10
               .TextRange.Bold = msoTrue
               .MarginBottom = 0
               .MarginLeft = 0
               .MarginTop = 0
               .MarginRight = 0
          End With
      Next j
Next i

With BREtable.Table
     .Columns(1).Width = 28.8
     .Cell(1,1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "KWT"
     .Cell(1,1).Shape.Fill.Forecolor.RGB = RGB(0,0,0)
     .Cell(1,1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255,192,0)
     .Cell(2,1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "0600"
     .Cell(3,1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "0700"
     ...
     .Cell(25,1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "0500"

     .Columns(2).Width = 28.8
     .Cell(1,2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "GMT"
     .Cell(1,2).Shape.Fill.Forecolor.RGB = RGB(255,192,0)
     .Cell(1,2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
     .Cell(2,2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "0400"
     .Cell(3,2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "0500"
     ...
     .Cell(25,2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "0300"

     .Columns(3).Width = 28.8
     .Cell(1,3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "EDT"
     .Cell(1,3).Shape.Fill.Forecolor.RGB = RGB(0,0,0)
     .Cell(1,3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255,192,0)
     .Cell(2,3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "2300"
     .Cell(3,3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "0000"
     ...
     .Cell(25,3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "2200"

     .Columns(4).Width = 120.6
     .Cell(1,4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Mon"
     .Cell(1,4).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242,242,242)
     .Cell(1,4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fond.Color = RGB(0,0,0)

     .Columns(5).Width = 120.6
     .Cell(1,5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Tues"
     .Cell(1,5).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242,242,242)
     .Cell(1,5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fond.Color = RGB(0,0,0)

     .Columns(6).Width = 120.6
     .Cell(1,6).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Wed"
     .Cell(1,6).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242,242,242)
     .Cell(1,6).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fond.Color = RGB(0,0,0)

     .Columns(7).Width = 120.6
     .Cell(1,7).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Thurs"
     .Cell(1,7).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242,242,242)
     .Cell(1,7).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fond.Color = RGB(0,0,0)

     .Columns(8).Width = 120.6
     .Cell(1,8).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Fri"
     .Cell(1,8).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242,242,242)
     .Cell(1,8).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fond.Color = RGB(0,0,0)

     .Columns(9).Width = 28.8
     'Repeat Column 3
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hiding the table

```
Dim t
'.....
BREtable.Visible = False
t = Timer
For i = 2 To BREtable.Table.Rows.Count
     BREtable.Table.Rows(i).Height = 19.44
Next i
BREtable.Visible = True
Debug.Print Timer - t
'.....
```

In my quick tests, that change cut execution of the block from ~1.3 sec to ~0.3-0.4 sec

Comment: That definitely helps. My time for executing that block is 28.8 sec even after hiding